# a problem about a convex function

Tags: inequality

I'm trying to prove that $ (1+x^2)^ {1/2} $ is a convex function; however after squaring both side twice of $ (1+(tx)^2)^ {1/2} + (1+((1-t)y)^2)^ {1/2} > (1+(tx+(1-t)y)^2)^ {1/2}$ I got so many terms which does lead to any useful result.
Can anyone give me some hint?

(x is a function but may not be differentiable)

Comment: Consider the second derivative of that function, show that it's positive.

Answer (score 2):

$f''(x) = (1+x^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}} > 0$. The answer follows.

Comment: Thanks. And how about when x itself is a function but is not differentiable?

Comment: for that case it won't be convex.